# Can I detect if SSL/https is enabled for an ASP.NET website from within the site's code?

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl, https, system.web

I'm working on a CMS that can run either with or without https enabled on the webserver. I'd like to be able to detect whether https is enabled or not, so that I can act accordingly (for example, display some https-related options to the administrator, and redirect to https for administrator logins).

I'm not looking for Request.IsSecureConnection because that only tells me if the current request is via https. I want something that will tell me whether the current bindings for the site in IIS include a binding for https at the same domain as the current request is on. So, for example, even if the current request is for `http://example.com/` and thus not secure, I want to know whether `https://example.com/` would work so I can (for example) redirect the user to it if they log in as administrator.

I've had no luck looking for anything in System.Web.Configuration that will tell me about the bindings of the current site, though.

My current workaround is just to require the administrator to set an appSetting in web.config if https is enabled, but I'd prefer if I could make it automatic. Having to set the same thing twice - once in IIS and once in web.config - is confusing.

Comment: I'm confused as to why checking the request isn't sufficient?

Comment: Because, if the site is running on `http://example.com/` and also `https://example.com/`, when someone visits `http://example.com/` that's not a secure connection. But I still need to know that `https://example.com/` *would* work, so that I can (for example) redirect the user to it when they log in as administrator.

Comment: I worked on an application with a similar requirement. We decided just to stick with the config setting so the customer could choose whether to use HTTPS or not. Detecting whether SSL was supported did not work for a couple reasons: one, we had to support various versions of IIS; two, we had one customer whose site supported SSL and they had it configured but for whatever reason they didn't want to use SSL for our app, even when logging in. (Don't recall why, this was like four years ago...) Anyway, my point is that it may be easier/better to just make them configure it when installing.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to make an https request to the site from the site and if it succeeds then you know https is supported.  Cache this in a static variable so it's only called once per app invocation.

Comment: That can fail, though: sometimes with NAT the server can't access its own public IP address. I've seen that happen. (Plus it's icky and it's hard to believe there isn't a way for a site to examine it's own hosting environment configuration...)

Comment: @Stuart, unfortunately a site can't examine it's own configuration by default due to security restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your IIS version you can use managemed .net code to do administrative tasks in IIS7. This is an example of querying a site for its bindings to see if https is enabled

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.bindingcollection(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: Yes, but Microsoft.Web.Administration isn't usable from within code running inside the site itself, is it? The website code doesn't run with administrative permissions for obvious reasons.

Comment: I just tested this to confirm, and I definitely get a permission denied error. Which is understandable because that API would give me access to the configuration of the entire server; having access to that would be a security risk. But the configuration of *the site that's currently running* isn't a security risk, surely?

Comment: @Stuart - you're correct, you need to be an administrator to use System.DirectoryServices or MWA to read a site's configuration from either the IIS6 metabase or applicationHost.config. The reason for this is that configuration data isn't locked down within the metabase or applicationHost.config on per-site basis. There is an exception in IIS7 if you're using feature delegation but that data is only accessible via MMC.

Comment: @Kev - right - so do you know of a supported way to programmatically find out the bindings of the current site, or specifically whether it has an https binding? Or are you saying that there really is no way and I need to require the administrator to tell me manually?